# Telerik Xamarin Image Editor Cropping

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, telerik, crop

I'm developing an Android app that can capture image from the camera. Currently there is a toolbox bar from Telerik where I can do the image editing such as Cropping. However, I want to preset the cropping border(rectangle box) size/position based on certain logic, how can I set the cropping box size/position from the backend(xaml.cs file)?

I try the code below but it doesn't work. I don't even know if this is the correct method, was just trying around.

```
var x = new CropCommandContext();
x.BindingContext = imageEditor;
x.Bounds = new Rectangle(5, 10, 10, 10);
x.Geometry = new RadRectangleGeometry(new Rectangle(5, 10, 10, 10), x.Bounds.Size);
imageEditor.CropCommand.Execute(x);
```